# codeigniter mysql error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my model

```
public function getDetails($ip)
    {
        $this->db->select('country_code, country_name');
        $this->db->where("'2323' BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num");
        return $this->db->get('ip')->row();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown column ''2323'' in 'where clause'

SELECT `country_code`, `country_name` FROM (`ip`) WHERE `2130706433` BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num
```

Where I`m wrong ?

Comment: $this->db->where("'2323' BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num");
Is actually

$this->db->where("$ip BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num");

Comment: where you are wrong? everywhere...you are misunderstanding the `between()` function! hope the answer on your previous question will clear things up for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2323` is evaluated as a column name, and `begin_ip_num` and `end_ip_num` as values. You must do the opposite, like this :

```
<?php
public function getDetails($ip)
    {
        $this->db->select('country_code, country_name');
        $this->db->where("begin_ip_num <= 2323 AND end_ip_num >= 2323");
        return $this->db->get('ip')->row();
    }
```

See [MySQL Reference on 'BETWEEN'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) for how this should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
$this->db->where("$ip BETWEEN begin_ip_num AND end_ip_num");
```

Because `$ip` is coming from your model function something you want to check against.